# Using Documents Directory for HTML Img

Tags: ios

I'm trying to use the app's Documents directory to store images, and later access then with a webview with html. I tried using the /var/mobile/Applications/id/Documents but that didn't work. Is there a way to access those files in the webview?

Comment: How did you try it? In what sense didn't it work?

Comment: Seems to be the most popular topic today. [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13136730/1577106

Comment: I put the file path there inside a <img src> tag and the img tag just showed a broken image. I also tried with file:/// and then the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I missed a / so it should of been file:///var/mobile/Applications/id/Documents  then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For save image you have to download image like a NSMutableData in your Cache directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/imageTemp.png",cachesDirectory];
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

After donwload you can move your image to your Document directory:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *arrayPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [arrayPath objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *cacheImagePath = filePath;
NSError *error;
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:cacheImagePath toPath:documentPath error:&error];
```

Comment: ok, how does this work when I want to access the image from the html? for example, I want to be able to have the html and/or the javascript point the img src to that particular image in the documents directory

Comment: dosen't relate to my question but figured it out. thanks anyways